# Are you Vs You are

Tags: word-order

I was wondering if you let me know which group of the self-made sentences below grammatically is corect:

**A)**

> - Where in the world **are you**?
> - What in the world **are you** doing here?
> - Who in the world do you think **are you**?

**B)**

> - Where in the world **you are**?
> - What in the world **you are** doing here?
> - Who in the world do you think **you are**?

I don't know which one ("are you" OR "you are") grammatically is correct in above constructions. I would be thankful if you somehow explain me the words order in "wh" questions like those.

Answer (score 4):

> Where in the world **are you**?
>   What in the world **are you** doing here?

These are simple sentences, in the sense that that they each contain exactly one clause.  The interrogative mode is marked by subject/operator inversion.

> Who in the world **do you** think [that] you are?

This is a complex sentence, in the sense that a matrix clause contains a subordinate clause.  The matrix clause is interrogative, as marked by subject/auxiliary inversion.  The subordinate clause is *not* interrogative and does not have subject/operator inversion.  Instead, the indicative subordinate clause acts as the direct object of the verb "do think".

In all three questions, there is only one instance of subject/verb inversion, and that instance is part of the clause which asks a question.  The clause which doesn't ask a question doesn't show inversion.

Answer (score 1):

Both sets of sentences contain at least one error. The correct set of sentences are

- Where in the world are you?
- What in the world are you doing here?
- Who in the world do you think you are?

Answer (score 1):

According to Cambridge, you use the phrase what/who/how to emphasize your surprise when asking a question.  Here it doesn't mean an indirect question.

So the first and second sentences under (A) and the third under (B) are grammatical.

The first and second sentences are quite clear. As for the third sentence, when you put the beginning clause in the interrogative, you don't use the other clause in the interrogative. For examples:

Do you know where he is?

Who do you think he is talking to?