# Which one is correct? "what item ARE YOU looking for?" or "what item YOU ARE looking for?"

Tags: word-order, questions

Which one is correct?

> What item *are you* looking for?

or

> What item *you are* looking for?

In British English if it's important.

Comment: [What **do you** think](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/inversion.html)?

Comment: It is a direct question, so the first one is correct. If it were an embedded question, the second would be correct: *I don't know [what X **you are**] looking for*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are you Vs You are.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110069/are-you-vs-you-are) It doesn't matter if we're talking about British or American English (or Australian, Canadian,...). In standard English we invert the **subject+verb** sequence to form questions (Statement: ***You are** mad*, Question: ***Are you** mad?*).